# Automapper map list of flat models to complex entity with inner lists

Tags: .net, .net-core, automapper

I have list of flat entities returned from sql query, of type:

```
public class Summary
{
    public int ApartmentId { get; set; }
    public int LoanId { get; set; }
    public int PaymentId { get; set; }

    public bool? RepaymentRequested { get; set; }
    public DateTime LoanStartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime PaymentDate { get; set; }
}
```

I need to Automap to group it to complex DTO structure

```
public class ApartmentSummaryDTO
{
    public int ApartmentId { get; set; }
    public bool? RepaymentRequested { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<LoanSummaryDTO> LoanSummaries { get; set; }
}

public class LoanSummaryDTO
{
    public int LoanId { get; set; }
    public DateTime LoanStartDate { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<PaymentSummaryDTO> PaymentSummaries { get; set; }
}

public class PaymentSummaryDTO
{
    public int PaymentId { get; set; }
    public DateTime PaymentDate { get; set; }
}
```

I can achieve it using LINQ like this:

```
                return data.GroupBy(d => d.ApartmentId)
                .Select(group => new ApartmentSummaryDTO()
                {
                    ApartmentId = group.Key,
                    RepaymentRequested = group.FirstOrDefault()?.RepaymentRequested,
                    LoanSummaries = group.GroupBy(loanGroup => loanGroup.LoanId).Select(l => new LoanSummaryDTO()
                    {
                        LoanId = l.Key,
                        LoanStartDate = l.First().LoanStartDate,
                        PaymentSummaries = l.Select(p => new PaymentSummaryDTO() 
                        {
                            PaymentId = p.PaymentId,
                            PaymentDate = p.PaymentDate
                        })
                    })
                }).FirstOrDefault();
```

But can't understand how to create configuration via automapper to get the same result as by LINQ.

Comment: AM doesn't group by, that part you need to write yourself. So if those are all your properties, perhaps not use AM.

Comment: No it is not, there are bigger list of properties. To pass SO limitations had to cut some of them.

Comment: OK, so you'll have to mix the two, `ProjectTo` and the manual group by.